# Imprimir un array sin que se vuelvan a imprimir los valores anteriores

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy haciendo una especie de *carrito* en el que el usuario ingresa los platos que desea consumir, y luego se imprimen en pantalla. Lo que me sucede es que cada vez que el usuario ingresa un nuevo plato, se imprimen todos los platos anteriores nuevamente.

Entonces, si yo ingresé primero "plato vegano" se imprimirá "plato vegano". Si luego ingreso "plato común" en pantalla se verá "plato vegano plato vegano plato común". Y así por cada vez que agregue un dato nuevo.

¿Cómo debería hacer para que se impriman **solamente** los nuevos datos?

```
function crearCard() {
        for (let w = 0; w < arrayPlatos.length; w++) {
            carrito.append(`<div class="kart-card">
            <p class="negrita">${arrayPlatos[w].plato}</p>
            <p>$ ${arrayPlatos[w].costo}</p>
        </div>`)
        }
    }
```

Comment: si solo quieres mostrar un dato entonces no hagas un `for`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás haciendo todo en un ciclo, siempre recorres todo el arreglo y por eso se repiten. Deberías tomar solo el último elemento y agregarlo:

```
function crearCard() {
    // Tomar solo el último elemento, en otra variable para simplificar
    let plato = arrayPlatos[arrayPlatos.length - 1];
    carrito.append(`<div class="kart-card">
            <p class="negrita">${plato.plato}</p>
            <p>$ ${plato.costo}</p>
        </div>`);
    }
}
```